# I am trying to prevent an email from being sent when a value is being sent

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

I have built a checkout system for our engines at work. Part of the program is the checkout has to be done daily. I created a script that sends an email when it has not been filled out for the day. It works great and I have it on a trigger to go off everyday at 9 and 10. Now these rigs sometimes go out of service and they do not need to do the checks while it is out. I made it so when they put the rig out of service it reflects in their daily record.

I thought I had it working correctly, but I had the first rig go out of service and it still sent out the email. I thought that having the condidtion of IF the value in column three is not "Out of service" it will continue, and if it did say "Out of service" that would stop the script. What did I do wrong with the code?

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/134DFqUNgUihWacm3hNd4B9Zqe-BYubYRXd-hh15fgK8/edit?usp=sharing

```
function myFunction() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var lastRow = CountColA();
  var lastDate = new Date(sheet.getRange(lastRow,1).getValues());
  var thisDate = new Date();
  var DateDiff = (thisDate.getTime() - lastDate.getTime())/1000/60/60/24;
  var emailSent = lastRow[3]; // Third column
    if (emailSent != "Out of service") { // Prevents sending duplicates
    if (DateDiff > 0.35) {
    MailApp.sendEmail("email@gmail.com" + "," + "email@gmail.com", "Unit Has Not Signed Narcotics Form", "BR133 has not signed the narcotics log today");
  } 
}
}

function CountColA() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  for(var i = data.length-1 ; i >=0 ; i--){
    if (data[i][0] != null && data[i][0] != ''){
      return i+1 ;
    }
  }}
```

Answer (score 0):

`CountCola()` returns an integer or nothing;

`var lastRow = CountColA();`

`var emailSent=lastrow[3];` but `lastRow` is not an array.

So it's hard to say what emailSent is in this line: `if (emailSent != "Out of service")`

Comment: Then how do I make it an array?

Comment: Are you sure that you want an array?

Comment: I dont know... I have zero training in how to do this. Most my stuff is by trail and error.

Comment: I've had no formal training either but then I don't usually let other people write my code for me because I would never learn how to do it myself and if I don't understand it I can't debug it.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the `CountColA` function to get the last row. You can simply use getLastRow function [1]:

```
sheet.getLastRow();
```

And get column C value like this:

```
sheet.getRange(lastRow, 3).getValue();
```

Also, I tested your code and `lastDate` variable isn't correct, so you should review how to create a Date from a string [2] or put a data validation for Date in the timestamp column so you can retrieve a Date value directly.

[1] https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getlastrow

[2] https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date